# How to let elements (as UIImageView) float in an UIView using constraints

Tags: ios, interface-builder, constraints, floating

I have 10 images with fixed dimensions (width, height). How do I choose the constraints in the Interface Builder when I want to let all images automatically float without any margin?

Like this, in Portrait mode the images would be aligned as

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
```

and in Landscape

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

In HTML with this effect would be automatic for the `<img>` tag, or when you have block elements as `<div>` you would apply `float:left` to all elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing the default behavior of a UICollectionView with a UICollectionViewFlowLayout, so maybe the simplest way is to use that, and let the flow layout lay out the image views for you.

If you *don't* want to do that, then you will simply have to perform layout yourself, supplying one set of constraints when the app orientation switches to portrait and a different set when the app orientation switches to landscape.